# Tune RabbitMQ Server to handle more request

Tags: python, django, docker, rabbitmq, celery

The scenario is that we are pushing messages in JSON format in bulk to an HTTP end point which we call as the coordinator.
The coordinator does two things:

1. Encrypt the message
2. Pushes this message via RabbitMQ and celery to a message broker over TCP.

We are able to process 1k requests per second with 2 workers and 8 concurrencies. The configuration of server is 8 CPU 32 GB RAM.

The challenge is to tune RabbitMQ to handle around 40k requests per second on the same infrastructure.

Our Stack:
Django, Python, Celery, RabbitMQ, Mongo, Docker, AWS

can this be done ? and How ?

Comment: Are you sure RabbitMQ is the limiting factor here?

Comment: They published/consumed way bigger numbers https://www.rabbitmq.com/blog/2012/04/25/rabbitmq-performance-measurements-part-2/ . May be your consumers not sending acks fast to get to high numbers?

Comment: Is this all on one server?  i.e., is celery running on the same machine as rabbitmq?

Comment: @2ps Yes, rabbitmq & celery are running on the same machine

Comment: You can increase the throughput by neglecting consumer acknowledgements. But if acknowledgements are your priority, then you can add more consumers to consume more messages at the same time. This can increase your throughput.